# Pass a template variadic function and its arguments to a function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, std-function, template-argument-deduction, stdbind

I would like to be able to pass a function taking any number of arguments, plus the matching arguments, as arguments to a function. This is what I've tried so far, I'm lost as I don't quite get a grasp at how parameter-packs work.

```
template <class T, typename... Args>
static void BindAction(const std::string& name, T* owner, const std::function<void(T*, Args...)>& func, Args... args)
{
    for (InputAction& action : m_actions)
        if (action.m_name == name)
            action.BindFunction(std::bind(func, owner, args...));
}
```

And I test it with these:

```
void Test(float f, std::string s, int i);

BindAction<Simulation>("Test", this, &Simulation::Test, 5.f, "a string", 2);
```

The error is simply that no instance of function template "`BindAction()`" matches the argument list.

Please don't dumb down the problem by telling me to call `std::bind()` and then passing the resulting function as argument. I really want the call to be that way. And if this is not possible, too bad but only then will I check for other solutions.

Comment: A member function is not an std::function. A function template requires an (almost) exact match, no implicit user-defined conversions are inserted for you.

Comment: What do you mean "A member function is not an std::function"? If I remove the concept of adding arguments, I can totally pass a member function as an std::function.

Comment: I don't understand the ` return action.BindFunction(std::bind(func, owner, args...));` what is that line supposed to do? Are you just trying to call the function?

Comment: Moreover, are you considering standard functions or member functions? To call a member function, need `this` somewhere, agree?

Comment: I'm adding the function to a map. This part does not matter, as what comes next works already. Yeah, I'm passing ``this`` as argument to the function, this is "T*"

Comment: If you remove the arguments, then you don't have a type to deduce, so a user-defined conversion is possible in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You're binding all of the arguments, so your map will actually be full of `std::function<void()>`, it won't match the incoming function. You can couple lambdas with `std::invoke` for a more predictable result, and simply use a template to deduce the type of the incoming callable:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Actions {
 public:
  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  void BindAction(const std::string& name, F f, Args... args) {
    actions_.emplace(
      name,
      [f, args...] () mutable { return std::invoke(f, args...); }
    );
  }

  void call(const std::string& name) {
    actions_[name]();
  }

 private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> actions_;
};
```

And a simple use example:

```
class Cls {
  public:
    void do_func(int i) {
      std::cout << "Cls::do_func(" << i << ")\n";
    }
};

int main() {
  Cls c;
  Actions actions;
  actions.BindAction("test", &Cls::do_func, c, 1);
  actions.call("test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The are some problems in your code.

In no particular order

(1) `BindAction()` receive a `std::function<void(T*, Args...)> const &`, for some `T` e `Args...` types to be deduced, but you pass to it a `&Simulation::Test`, so a pointer to a (`static`?) method of a class/struct, that isn't a `std::function`.

You passing a pointer that can be converted to a `std::function` but isn't a `std::function`.

A sort of egg and chicken problem: the compiler can't convert the pointer to a `std::function` because doesn't know the `Args...` types and can't deduce the `Args...` types because doesn't receive a `std::function`

(2) you needs two different variadic lists of argument types: a `Args1...` list for the argument of the `std::function` and a second `Args2...` list for the arguments (`args...`) received.

See your call example

```
void Test(float f, std::string s, int i); 

BindAction<Simulation>("Test", this, &Simulation::Test, 5.f, "a string", 2);
```

The `Test()` method receive a `float`, a `std::string` and a `int`; but `BindAction()` receive a `float`, a `char const [9]` and a `int`.

If you use a single `Args...` list, the compiler can't deduce the types because has two different list of types.

(3) not sure but... your `BindAction()` is a `static` method but uses (if I understand correctly) a member of the object (`m_action`)

<s>(4) your `BindAction()` method is a `void` method but return a function</s> [corrected]

Suggestions:

(a) receive the callable as a template type itself, without deducing the types of the arguments

(b) receive the list of argument as universal references and use template forwarding

To show a simplified example, something as follows

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename F, typename ... As>
static auto BindAction (F const & func, As && ... args)
 { return std::bind(func, std::forward<As>(args)...); }

void Test(float f, std::string s, int i)
 { std::cout << "f[" << f << "], s[" << s << "], i[" << i << "]" << std::endl; } 

int main ()
 { 
   auto ba = BindAction(Test, 5.f, "a string", 2);

   std::cout << "post BindAction(), pre ba()\n";

   ba();
 }
```